# What is the language recognized by the finite automaton?

Tags: computer-science, automata, computational-mathematics

I have no idea how to approach this?

[image]

Comment: What languages have you tried?

Comment: @Galen I haven't tried a programming language, and that is not I was asking. I should have phrased it better. I mean it like A = {w| w ....}. I think I figured it out from the rest of the answers. Thank you for helping though.

Comment: I didn't mean a programming language either, I meant a [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language).

Comment: You mean like DFA, NFA? If that is what you're talking about then it's a DFA @Galen

Comment: NFA vs DFA is definitely a good distinction to make. I was thinking more fundamentally about what subsets of the free monoid of your alphabet you had looked at up until you had asked your question.

Comment: @Galen  Initially the states were 1,2,3 and it was an NFA, and I converted it to a DFA. That an interesting take though I didn't think about it that way. Thanks

Comment: If you really have no idea how to approach this, then it's time to make an appointment to see the teacher. Believe me, the teacher wants to know how well his/her teaching is going over, where the rough spots are, etc.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That makes sense and thanks

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing with a [deterministic finite automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) according to the provided picture. It is defined as a $5$-tuple $(Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F)$.

- The set of states: $Q=\{\{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{2,3\}\}$
- The set of input symbols $\Sigma=\{a,b, \epsilon\}$
- The transition function $\delta: Q \times \Sigma \to Q:(\{1,2\},a) \mapsto \{1,2,3\}$, $(\{1,2,3\},a) \mapsto \{1,2,3\}$, $(\{1,2,3\},b) \mapsto \{2,3\}$, $(\{2,3\},b) \mapsto \{2,3\}$, $(\{2,3\},a) \mapsto \{1,2\}$
- The inital state $q_0:=\{1,2\}$
- The set of accept states $F \subseteq Q$, which is $Q$

So you always start with $a$ or $\epsilon$ (notice that the empty word is accepted because the initial state is an accept state).

Example of accepted words: $aabbb$, $a$, $aba$

Example of unaccepted words: $b$, $bbabaaaaaba$

Can you go from here?

Comment: The empty string is also accepted.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I‘ve corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to think of an automaton as some kind of "Snakes and Ladders Game". The circles which represent states correspond to the squares in the board game. The arrows represent movement from one square to another. The label on the arrow specifies which input ("dice throw") leads to that move. In board game there is a designated square reaching which is the goal. Here some states are marked specially to designate final state(s).

The language recognized by an  automaton is the sequence of dice throws (inputs) which start from a specially marked initial state and lead to the final state.

The problem you stated was "I have  no idea ...". Now  I have given you an Idea that will help you solve this kind of problems.